# How can I view definitions of PHP functions?

Tags: php

I know PHP's native code is compiled and what we write is interpreted.

Is there a way I can view definitions of inbuilt functions like `isset()`, `strlen()`, `strrev()`, etc?

I use LAMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at [PHP's source code](https://github.com/php/php-src). Example: [strrev](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/0ecffc8af6bcf6e33e26df1ff6478b838b4bb98b/ext/standard/string.c#L3487-L3512).

Comment: Thanks for the awesome links! +1. I downloaded the source code and searched definition of function `isset` but couldn't find. Do you have any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5b52a44860fbb0b86081ec7a81b2e82369db9f08/Zend/zend_vm_def.h#L6207

It looks a bit messier than strrev because it's actually a language construct rather than a real function.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.php.net will show you all the functions needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But http://php.net gives usage documentation and not the actual definition. :)

Comment: `https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen` strlen — Get string length | Returns the length of the given string.